# How to handle plain text, server response in Angular 2?

Tags: typescript, angular

How to handle plain text server response in Angular 2?

I am using the following:

```
    this.http.get('lib/respApiTest.res')
    .subscribe(testReadme => this.testReadme = testReadme);
```

lib/respApiTest.res

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim 
veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
```

But I am getting a JSON format example:

```
{"_body":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet......"}
```

Right now I'm using something like the following to handle: (this.testReadme._boby)

```
    alert(this.testReadme._boby);
```

This works well but is this the way to handle plain text in Angular 2 ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`response.text()`](https://angular.io/api/http/Response) method...

```
this.http.get('lib/respApiTest.res')
  .subscribe(testReadme => this.testReadme = testReadme.text());
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew his answer would work, as elsewhere use .json (), but I could not find anything like what you answered in the documentation thanks

Comment: I upvote, but now I can not accept, but I accept it after, thanks for your time

Comment: Nor .text() or .json() is present in reference for class Response: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/Response-class.html